# How do you concatenate the same string to every element in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, concatenation

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
list = ["apple", "lemon", "Shepherd's", "steak and kidney"]
```

I might want to add the word 'pie' onto the end of every element - without manually typing into the list. The result should be:

```
list = ["apple pie", "lemon pie", "Shepherd's pie", "steak and kidney pie"]
```

Any ideas as to how I would do this? (This isn't my actual code btw, pie was just on my mind)

Comment: Have you learned loops yet?

Comment: Might want to look up list comprehensions.

Comment: **never** use a builtin python type(list) as a variable.

Comment: `l = [i + " pie" for i in l]`

Comment: There is no need for the sarcastic comments. I am not an expert, yet no one has successfully answered my question.

Comment: @123BearHoney I apologize if I came across as rude. I was simple telling you that you should never use a python builtin type, such as `list`, for a variable.  As for your question. use list comprehension: `lst = [str(i) + ' ' + str(word) for i in lst]`

Comment: That's ok @Mr.Python. Thank you David Zemens as well for the most helpful suggestions. I would give you both a thumbs up but I have not got a good enough reputation.